# How to execute code every x seconds in unity?

Tags: unity

So I have a flashlight battery script I created and I need to know how do you make the battery variable go down every few seconds(whatever time you set.) I tried `InvokeRepeating` but it was an absolute disaster (The battery variable just went down really fast and ignored my script). Anyways this is the code I have:

```
void Update ()
{
    if (light == false) {
        battery+=0;
    }
    if (light == true) {
        battery--;//This is what I want to have every few seconds
    }

    if (battery == 0) {
        myLight.enabled = false;
        light =false;
        battery++;
        InvokeRepeating("invoke", 1, 0.01F);
    }
}

void invoke(){
    light = false;
    myLight.enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: This question is actually about how to fix your code, I think it's a poor question. Also, in the future, please only include the code related to the problem in your question.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track with [`InvokeRepeating`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html). However, three issues:

1. You're currently calling your `invoke` method every .01 seconds.
2. Your `invoke` method disables your `myLight` component, rather than decreasing `battery`.
3. Your `invoke` method is a very confusing name.

*I'm not sure you're calling `InvokeRepeating` in a good spot, but I'll let you test that :)*

I'd suggest changing your `invoke` method to something like this:

```cs
void DecreaseBattery(){
    battery--;
}
```

Then edit your `InvokeRepeating` call:

```cs
InvokeRepeating("DecreaseBattery", 30f, 30f);
```

This will invoke DecreaseBattery after 30 seconds, and then every 30 seconds thereafter.

If you ever need to cancel or restart the `InvokeRepeating` call, you may want to use `CancelInvoke();` somewhere to ensure multiple repeats don't overlap.